# how can i add a single leaderboard with level and high score in google play services

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I want to sort the player score according to the level and no of death till that level in the leaderboard of google play services .
for example player one is at level 20 with no of death 200.

---

player 2 is at level 15 with no of death 150

---

player 3 is at level 25 with no of death 250.

---

player 4 is at level 25 with no of death 300

---

.

the leaderboard should show

---

player 3 25/250

---

player 4 25/300

---

player 1 20/200

---

player 2 15/150

---

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Google Play Developer account and the [Unity play games plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

Then you can read up on the documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.CreateLeaderboard.html).

Comment: I did that but is there any way that i can upload both features leve and no of death in a single leaderboard ?

Comment: @sagar I personally have never used the leaderboard feature but I do know that in the Google Play Developer Console you can format the data to some extent, so you could see if that works for you but personally I think it would just be better and easier to go with two leaderboards.